# Saving an img buffer as BMP file is turning black in Android

Tags: android, c++, image, android-ndk

I have an img buffer and I'm trying to save it to bmp file.
I cast the buffer to unsigned long so I can access the pixel values.
I made a try and painted the img in red and it work correctly.

```
    unsigned char* pTextureBuffer = static_cast<unsigned char*>((pTexture->GetBuffer())->lock(Ogre::HardwareBuffer::HBL_NORMAL));
    unsigned long* pTextureBufferPixel = (unsigned long*)pTextureBuffer;


        int w=(int)uTextureWidthInPixels; 
        int h=(int)uTextureHeightInPixels;

        FILE *f;
        unsigned char *img = NULL;
        int filesize = 54 + 3*w*h;  //w is your image width, h is image height, both int
        if( img )
            free( img );
        img = (unsigned char *)malloc(3*w*h);
        memset(img,0,sizeof(img));

        for(int i=0; i<w; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<h; j++)
            {
                int x=i; int y=(h-1)-j;

                unsigned long r = 255;
                unsigned long g = 0;
                unsigned long b = 0;

                img[(x+y*w)*3+2] = (unsigned char)(r);
                img[(x+y*w)*3+1] = (unsigned char)(g);
                img[(x+y*w)*3+0] = (unsigned char)(b);
            }
        }

        unsigned char bmpfileheader[14] = {'B','M', 0,0,0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 54,0,0,0};
        unsigned char bmpinfoheader[40] = {40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,0, 24,0};
        unsigned char bmppad[3] = {0,0,0};

        bmpfileheader[ 2] = (unsigned char)(filesize    );
        bmpfileheader[ 3] = (unsigned char)(filesize>> 8);
        bmpfileheader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(filesize>>16);
        bmpfileheader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(filesize>>24);

        bmpinfoheader[ 4] = (unsigned char)(       w    );
        bmpinfoheader[ 5] = (unsigned char)(       w>> 8);
        bmpinfoheader[ 6] = (unsigned char)(       w>>16);
        bmpinfoheader[ 7] = (unsigned char)(       w>>24);
        bmpinfoheader[ 8] = (unsigned char)(       h    );
        bmpinfoheader[ 9] = (unsigned char)(       h>> 8);
        bmpinfoheader[10] = (unsigned char)(       h>>16);
        bmpinfoheader[11] = (unsigned char)(       h>>24);

        f = fopen("//sdcard//tex//a.bmp","wb");
        fwrite(bmpfileheader,1,14,f);
        fwrite(bmpinfoheader,1,40,f);
        for(int i=0; i<h; i++)
        {
            fwrite(img+(w*(h-i-1)*3),3,w,f);
            fwrite(bmppad,1,(4-(w*3)%4)%4,f);
        }
        fclose(f);
```

Now I replaced this:

```
unsigned long r = 255;
unsigned long g = 0;
unsigned long b = 0;
```

with:

```
    unsigned long r = (pTextureBufferPixel[i*uTextureWidthInPixels + j]) & 0xff; 
    unsigned long g = (pTextureBufferPixel[i*uTextureWidthInPixels + j] >> 8) & 0xff;
    unsigned long b = (pTextureBufferPixel[i*uTextureWidthInPixels + j] >> 16) & 0xff;
```

to save the img from the buffer but I get all black.
The black img occurs only in `android` while in windows the img saved correctly.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you even created the file? //sdcard// is not valid file name for android, it's a folder

Comment: `an img buffer and I'm trying to save it to bmp file.`. A byte buffer? What is in it? How did you fill it? Android does not support bmp files but probably this will not matter if you know what you do.

Comment: @OlegBogdanov - yes I actually write the file to "//sdcard//tex//" not "//sdcard//" , my bad but same issue

Comment: @greenapps - not sure, I use ogre to fill it

Comment: `"//sdcard//tex//"`. That still would be a folder. And why not a file name with the right extension roght away?

Comment: `fwrite(bmpfileheader,1,14,f);`. You should check the return value of course.

Comment: It is unclear what your save to file problem has to do with your red/black problem. Where and how do you display it so you know?

Comment: `but I get all black.`. Well what do you get instead of 255,0,0? All FF or all 00?

Comment: @greenapps - forgot to copy the full path, fixed it.

Comment: @greenapps - I just made a check to be sure I write and save the img correctly (with red img), and then I try to write from the buffer.
How can I check that? I just got black img, thats what  I see

Comment: It is still unclear how you display that image file. Or what are you doing to see the result.

Comment: `cast the buffer to unsined long so I can access the pixel values.`,. I would not do that to begin with when pixel rgb values are represented by bytes. Or in your case unsigned char. I would directly read the original unsigned char buffer.

Comment: not sure I understand how, any chance for example?

Comment: As this is not the real problem i think i will not do that. You first better answer the questions.

Comment: ok so the values are rgb= 0,0,0

Comment: So your three new lines all put the value 0. Well concentrate on those three lines. What do they retrieve that the result is always 0? What is in the original buffer? Check it! Are all values 0?

Comment: If you save the original buffer to file then what do you get?

Comment: `save the img correctly (with red img), and then I try to write from the buffer. ` ???? After you saved the image? Why would you do something after the image is saved? What do you mean with 'write from the buffer'?

Comment: these are 2 different cases, not in the same time of course.
And what i'm trying to do is save the ORIGINAL buffer which give me black img.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131440/discussion-between-arii-and-greenapps).

Comment: ???? Unclear what you alll do. When and why. How do you write the originsl buffer to file? And if it shows black than my first question 'whats in the buffer' is still valid. Please answer all questions to the point as this takes much to much time.

Comment: `pTexture->GetBuffer()`. You should have started explayning what `pTexture` is. And what `GetBuffer()` points to and delivers. And how many bytes for instance in that buffer?